# run parameterized and non paramterized tests sequentially in a single TestNG test suite

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I have webdriver tests in different classes with some being parameterized and some non parameterized. I am having issues when running a test suite with both parameterized and non parameterized test . The paramertized test start before the non paramertized finish although I have set the parallel attribute to be false. 
First, I tried creating different tests in the suite with parameterized and non paramertized tests in different test but that didn't work.
Secondly, I created different suite files and linked them . However, this works only when the parameterized suite is started first but not the other way round.

```
<suite-files>
   <suite-file path="./ParameterizedTest.xml" />
 </suite-files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to create the non-parametrize test to different XML an group under the suite-file, example:

```
<suite-files>
   <suite-file path="./ParameterizedTest.xml" />
   <suite-file path="./NoNParameterizedTest.xml" />
</suite-files>
```